# how to use "docker.commands.composeUp" with match and/or label property?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to understand how to properly use `match` property from [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose#_command-customization) but, frankly, I don't understand what I need to do, because every time I do `cmd+shift+P` "Docker: Compose Up" I still have to select the configuration file to run.

In my example, I have:

```json
    "docker.commands.composeUp": [
        {
            "label": "override",
            "template": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml docker-compose.override.yml  up -d --build",
            "match": "override"
        },
        {
            "label": "debug",
            "template": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml docker-compose.debug.yml up -d --build",
            "match": "debug"
        }
```

So, how is `regex` working here?